# django: sending unicode address to googmaps from form

Tags: python, django, google-maps, unicode

i'm using **googlemaps** http://py-googlemaps.sourceforge.net/ to show some travel info. i send **start_address** and **end_address** through a form and calculate route server-side.

everything works fine when i use basic ascii charaters in address, but if i use wild croatian characters such as *'čćšž'* i get *"'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position...".*

if i use

```
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps
directions = GoogleMaps().directions(smart_str(start_address), smart_str(end_address))
```

as a command **in shell it runs fine**, but not when i run through test server on the website.
start_address and end_address are both type unicode.

so how am i suppost to form start_address in order for it to function properly with whole unicode?

**Edit:**

after fiddling around some more this is the code that finally works:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode, smart_str
from googlemaps import GoogleMaps

def calculations(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        trip = {}
        start_address = smart_str(request.POST.get('start_address'))
        end_address = smart_str(request.POST.get('end_address'))
        directions = GoogleMaps().directions(start_address, end_address)
        trip['length'] = directions['Directions']['Distance']['html']
        trip['duration'] = directions['Directions']['Duration']['html']
        return render_to_response( 'index.html', {'trip':trip, }, context_instance = RequestContext(request) )
```

you can consider the issue closed :)

Answer (score 0):

`ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u010d' in position...` means, django tries to convert from Unicode to Ascii. What is your `settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET` value?

Try to set `settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET = 'UTF-8'`.

Comment: ouh, it wasn't set up :-/ but now i get _'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position ..._

Comment: Please, post a full ("working") code with the text which does not work.

Comment: thanks Alexander Artemenko for your help. got it working and posted my fully working code in the original post :)